# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown doesn't open

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

I have a page with two Bootstrap multiselect dropdowns. They're being created and rendering properly. (That is, I see a dropdown rather a regular select list.) But when I click on them, the dropdowns don't drop open.

To post here, I've simplified considerably. (I'm actually generating the options with PHP code. But even then, the Debugger shows me that the options are present.) I'm sure I must be missing something simple here, since I've gotten this working for another site and the code seems to be totally analogous.

HTML:

```
        <select id="confs" multiple="multiple">
        <option value='First' id='1'>First</option>
        <option value='Second' id='2'>Second</option>   
        </select>
```

Javascript (I'm including the whole Ready function here, to make sure there isn't something wrong there):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#papers").tablesorter();  
$('#confs').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    onChange: function(option, checked) {           
        updatePapers();         
    }
});
$('#cats').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    onChange: function(option, checked) {           
        updatePapers();         
    }
});
})
</script>
```

Don't know if it's significant, but the big difference between this site and the one where I have it working is that this one has Windows hosting, while the other is Linux.

**Update:** I've created an even simpler test page that contains just the single Bootstrap multiselect. I've added onDropdownShow code, to show an alert. The Alert appears, but the dropdown doesn't drop. Here's the new version of the Ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#confs').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    onDropdownShow: function(event) {
        alert('Dropdown shown.');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

After discovering that the dropdowns in my Bootstrap navbar wouldn't open either, I found that I was loading bootstrap.min.js twice. Once I fixed that, the navbar worked.

Since I'd already replaced the multiselect dropdown with another control, I haven't tested to confirm that this solves the problem here, but I feel reasonably confident that it will.

Comment: I was having the exact same issue then came across your solution! thank you. it solved mine

Answer (score 0):

Params? It's

onChange: function(option, checked, select)

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. Even if remove the event code, the dropdown won't even open.